# limitar usuários na database

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

eu procurei e não encontrei como se faz para limitar os usuários em uma DB...
Estou fazendo uma aplicação em C# usando 'sql server' e gostaria de saber como faço para que o userDB tenha no máximo 5 usuários, ao tentar por o 6º user o sistema avisa que já atingiu o máximo permitido..

O que eu não sei fazer aí, é checar quantos já existem na DB, de resto eu faço, e não da para fazer checando a id pois é possível deletar e fazer um novo usuário, sendo assim as ids vão passar de 5

PS: resolvi assim

```
private void btn_cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userDB";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon);
        Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("São permitidos apenas 5 usuários", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            var newuser = new cadastrodeusuario();
            newuser.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Ao limitar o número de conexões no banco não seria o sistema que avisaria, você teria que tratar uma exception vindo do banco ao recusar a conexão.

Comment: mas a questão é essa "O que eu não sei fazer aí, é checar quantos já existem na DB"

Comment: Você não vai checar, o SQL server irá retornar uma exception dizendo que não pode mais executar tua query e você trata a excpetion na sua aplicação.

Comment: qual é a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: Esse código parece funcionar, o q ta rolando?

Answer (score 0):

Seu código resolve o problema, mas eu faria de outra forma, se ocorrer algum problema a conexão vai ficar aberta, e não está fazendo close e dispose corretamente dos objetos:

```
int count;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userDB";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}

if (count == 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("São permitidos apenas 5 usuários", "Ficha de Anamnese - ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    var newuser = new cadastrodeusuario();
    newuser.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```